# Can't understand Unity3d Flight Script

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm trying to make a flight simulation in Unity3d. First I used `rigidbody.addforce()` but the movement did not respond good in rotation so I look forward to Unity3d samples and tried to use their code for controlling the airplane. It works just fine but I can't understand how it works. The code is this:

```
var newVelocity = Vector3.Lerp(rig.velocity, 
                               -transform.forward * EnginePower,
                               EnginePower * Time.deltaTime);

Debug.Log("Velocity:     " + rig.velocity + 
          "Forward:      " + -transform.forward * EnginePower + 
          "Vector3.Lerp: " + Vector3.Lerp(rig.velocity, -transform.forward * EnginePower, EnginePower * Time.deltaTime));

rig.velocity = newVelocity;
```

This code is in the `Update()` function, I tested it and tried to set it to `Start()`, the airplane is moving but did not respond to rotation. I tried to debug and see what changes, the thing is there is nothing that changes so much.

I just can't understand how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call this in your `Update()` function, since it's supposed to run every frame. `Vector3.Lerp()` does a **Linear interpolation** between two 3D vectors ([documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html)).

The first argument to the function, let's call it Vector A, `rig.velocity`, is the current velocity of your airplane. `-transform.forward * EnginePower`, Vector B, is your backwards direction scaled to your engine power - which is probably connected to a user input (gas gauge).

I'm not sure why `transform.forward` is reversed with `-`, but what lerp does is return a new vector, from Vector A to Vector B, scaled with a factor. If the factor is 0, Vector A is returned. If the factor is 1, Vector B is returned.

In your code the scale is `EnginePower * Time.deltaTime`, where `Time.deltaTime` is the time in seconds since the last frame - 0.016 seconds if you're running 60 FPS. So, you can understand, the scale becomes really small and so `Lerp` returns a vector very close to your current velocity, but ever so slightly towards Vector B. The next frame, it scales a bit more, and a bit more, etc. I hopes this improves your understanding.

You can use [`Debug.DrawLine()`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.DrawLine.html) to draw your vectors, use it like this:

```
 Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, rig.velocity, Color.red);
 Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, -transform.forward * EnginePower, Color.green);
```

This will draw two lines representing the vectors you are passing to `Lerp`. These lines are gizmos so sure to have gizmos turned on in the editor window to display them (top right corner, next to the stats button).

Comment: Many thanks. for edit and help. the thing is I see the debug return from vector3.lerp it's actually the same as rigidbody.velocity most of the time. but when I increase EnginePower Value the object goes faster every thing is move good but no change to vector3.lerp come out. the thing is I can't figure out the way it's work !!!!

Comment: Oh Now I got it Many Thanks ;)

Comment: @FDM.Pro Happy to help!